# How does Tasker share data with plugins?

Tags: tasker

After years of struggling with near "blindness" from using Tasker 1.3.3u2 on an old e-ink device (Android 2.1), I decided to take a serious look at modifying the theme. I finally managed to chase down all the textColors and change them to black while changing almost all backgrounds to white. This required changes in not only layout xmls but also a few smali files.

Needless to say, the signature is broken, but a resigned copy still functions well--except for plugins.

I knew this was coming because a few years ago a software update for the e-ink device made it refuse to install the original Tasker app--unless I resigned it. I still don't know why.

To the point: how does Tasker pass information to plugins? I thought there might be a shared uid but nothing in packages.xml suggests any connection between Tasker and any of the plugins I use (Minimalistic Text, Rotation Locker, Screenshot Easy, Desktop Visualizer).

Task steps involving plugins are ignored if Tasker is resigned. Compiled kid apps (using App Factory) work as intended, including plugins. This is good because I never use Tasker itself unless I am working on a new project or debugging an old one. I always make stand-alone apps.

But...I can keep one device with the original version of Tasker (and old software) for development, except the whole idea was to make it easier on my aging eyes when I'm doing serious creative work, so that's a loss.

Does anyone have an insight into how plugins communicate with Tasker and if there is a way I could restore those lines of communication in a resigned Tasker? (I've already tried resigning the plugin apps with the same signature. No dice.)

Comment: `sharedUserId` was also my first guess but have already excluded that. But there is a similar possibility using "signature protected" intents and services. Check the permission entries for one with protectionLevel=signature.

Comment: I was unable to find any instance of "protectionLevel=signature" in the manifest of either Tasker or any of the plugins (or packages.xml). I should have mentioned that I had occasion of resign RotationLocker a few years ago after retheming to make user options actually visible on the e-ink device. This resigned app still works with Tasker (the original signature) as a plugin. So whatever this is, it doesn't seem to depend on the plugins.

Comment: Tasker has [documentation for creating a plugin](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/plugins-intro.html), if it may provide any insight.

Comment: Yes, I've read through that. Unfortunately the technical nature is above my pay grade :-(